# Use a input txt file inside code to use as simulated input by user C language

Tags: c

I'm making a final work for my algorithm and data struct class, and I come to the point of checking the work with the professor input.txt files. I know how to run the input file throught the terminal, but i wanted to know if there is anyway I could somehow put that file.txt into sdin, so I could move with the debugger in codeblocks line by line, while it is inputing itself, so I can more easily check for errors.

Comment: In the op, I stated that I know how to run in the terminal, I'm trying to find a way to input inside the code and run the debugger in codeblocks, so I can receive the input, line by line, progressing trought the program, instead of getting all the output at the same time.

Comment: If I remember right, the way I used to use with gdb was 1) start debugging `gdb executable` 2) set breakpoint `break main` 3) run with redirection `run <file.txt`

Comment: That is a good question. But I may have a quick fix. Why don't you just write a `for` loop that reads `input.txt` line by line and applies your algorithm? That way, you can print out the line number and the text in the line and see exactly where it breaks.

Comment: Thats actually a great point. I'm gonna try to do that, thank you for the sugestion!